# HTTP requests/responses parser for C/C++

Tags: c++, c, http

I am building a simple reverse proxy in C. I am looking for an HTTP request/response parser. I need a way of checking if the request is well formed and also a way of addressing any header field, for example, char* con = request->connection;, or something similar. I have found many answers to this, but all of them are libraries that provide the http server itself, and I don't need that, I just need the parser not the http server.
Note: If the parser is for C++, there is no problem.